# querying efficiently a DataFrame

Tags: python, performance, pandas, query-performance

I have a very big DataFrame (more than 10m rows), here's a simplified version of it's columns:

```
Date    Owner     <Other Columns...>
```

I query it such that Date is within some range, the Owner is in some list:

```
df[(df.Date > start_date) & (df.Date < end_date) & df.Owner.isin(relevant_owners)]
```

This is the most time consuming part in my code.

I've tried changing relevant_users from list to set, since I thought that a lookup time of o(1) would increase performance - but it actually made it about 10 times slower.

I managed to gain 30% performance boost by using a dictionary instead of a DataFrame for storing the data, but I'd love to keep the DataFrame if I could make it more efficient.

Comment: Tried `df.query('Date > @start_date &  Date < @end_date & Owner in @relevant_owners')` and did you check instead of single multiple boolean check, do it 3 steps replacing `df`, so that next filtering would be on smaller `df`?

Comment: @JohnGalt Actually query() made it worse. and separating the query did not produce any significant improvement.